# MKAnnotation not displaying on map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to create a custom annotation for a simple map view of mine, but the annotaiton pin is not showing up on the map when i run the simulator.

I have a MapViewAnnotation class which implements the MKAnnotation protocol, and I have another MapViewController class where I programmatically create a mapView and display the map.

MapViewAnnotation.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(id) initWithTitle: (NSString *) title AndCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;

@end
```

MapViewAnnotation.m :

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title = _title;

-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title AndCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    self = [super init];
    _title = title;
    _coordinate = coordinate;
    return self; 
}
@end
```

MapViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) MKMapView *mapView;

-(void) goToLocation;
@end
```

MapViewController.m :

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

#define LATITUDE 42.3889;
#define LONGITUDE -72.5278;


@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
    [self goToLocation];
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self createAnnotations]];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) goToLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;

    newRegion.center.latitude = LATITUDE;
    newRegion.center.longitude = LONGITUDE;

    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.05f;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05f;

    self.mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = YES;
    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}


-(NSMutableArray *) createAnnotations {

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"location" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for (NSDictionary *row in locations){
        NSNumber *latitude = [row objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSNumber *longitude = [row objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coord.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;

        MapViewAnnotation *annotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:title AndCoordinate:coord];
        [annotations addObject: annotation];
    }

    return annotations;


}
@end
```

I am taking am going through a plist where I have coordinates for one test location that I am trying to show on my map, but the pin is not displaying on the map. Again, I am doing this all programmatically, no xib, or storyboards (although that should not be the problem).

I do not know why the annotation is not showing up. I tried looking on stack for some other situations like mine but was unlucky to find anything that could help.

Thank you.

Comment: Confirm that createAnnotations is actually adding annotations to the array and at the expected coordinates.  Eg. Right before the `[annotations addObject...` line, put `NSLog(@"title=%@, lat=%f, long=%f", title, coord.latitude, coord.longitude);`.  Does it correctly log all the annotations in the plist and are the coordinates correct?  If log is not what you expected, check that `path` is valid, that `locations` array is not empty, etc.

Comment: Yes it is. It's outputting the correct data. But I figured it out thanks to you.. I had one of the coordinates at 72.32 when it should had been -72.32

Answer (score 0):

Answer was pretty simple,

In my plist I had the coordinates

```
latitude: 42.37
longitude: 72.536
```

when it should of actually been `-72.536` for longitude.